# Unable to automate git fetch && git checkout using python

Tags: python, git, bitbucket

I have automated the process of git checkout a particular branch which a user want to enter. I am using the following python code with subprocess to do so ,

```
from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
from sys import argv
import subprocess

prompt = '> '

print "Enter the name of branch you need to clone: "
user_branch = raw_input(prompt)

print "You Entered: ",user_branch


print "this will do a git status"
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["git", "status"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = cmd.communicate()[0]
print output
#for line in output: # output.split("\n"):
if  ("Untracked files:" or "Changes not staged for commit") in  output:
     print "Need to do a Git stash"
     subprocess.Popen(["git", "stash"])
     subprocess.Popen(["git fetch && git checkout"+(user_branch)])
else:
     print "simply do git checkout userbranch"
     subprocess.Popen(["git","pull"])
     subprocess.Popen(["git fetch && git checkout"+(user_branch)])
```

This throws  :

```
Enter the name of branch you need to clone: 
> release_4_0
You Entered:  release_4_0
this will do a git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

simply do git checkout userbranch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git_updater.py", line 25, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["git fetch && git checkout"+(user_branch)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I want to input just the branch name that user wants to checkout . Does this makes sense ?

Comment: thats a type ,mybad .. updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen(["git fetch && git checkout"+(user_branch)])
```

should be

```
subprocess.Popen("git fetch && git checkout %s"%user_branch,shell=True)
```

or you could do somehting like

```
subprocess.Popen(["git", "fetch"]).communicate()
subprocess.Popen(["git", "checkout", user_branch])
```

the problem is if the argument is a list it expects comma separated file and arguments (and im not sure how the && would work)

Comment: The `&&` won't work. `&&` is a shell thing and by default, `subprocess` runs processes without invoking a shell. You can either add `shell=True` to the `Popen()` constructor, or you do the same thing in Python (retrieve the return code from `git fetch` and only call `git checkout` if it is zero, i.e., use two subprocess calls).

Comment: still says the same :( 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git_updater.py", line 25, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen("git fetch && git checkout %s"%user_branch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: trying the "or" option

Comment: thanks guys :) works the or stuff @kindall awesome explanation